# selectizeInput getting displayed above the absolutePanel - how to avoid

Tags: r, rstudio

Given below the code i used for displying selectizeInput  and  absolutePanel. selectizeInput is not getting merged with the page background. it is displaying above the absolutePanel. please help me to fix.

ui.r

```
library(shinydashboard)
      shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
          dashboardPage(skin = c("blue"),
                        dashboardHeader(title = "R Tools"
                        ),
                        ## Sidebar content
                        dashboardSidebar(
                          sidebarMenu(
                            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                            menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
                          )

                        ),
                        dashboardBody(
                                          box(
                                            title = "Tools", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                                            collapsible = TRUE,width = 4,
                                            uiOutput("showtxttruevalue"),
                                            uiOutput("showddllalternate")
                                          ),
                                          absolutePanel(
                                            bottom = 20, right = 60,top=200, width = "auto",
                                            draggable = TRUE,
                                            wellPanel(
                                            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                            aa")
                                            ), style = "opacity: 0.9"



                        )

          )


        ))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {




output$showtxttruevalue <- renderUI({
    numericInput(inputId="txttruevalue", label="TrueValue", value = 0)
 })


output$showddllalternate <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("ddllalternate", "Alternate:",c('unequal','less','greater'),   selected='<>')
  })



  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, use the `'left'` parameter while positioning the `absolutePanel()`. Use the following to position it.

```
absolutePanel(
                      left = 500, bottom = 20, right = 60,top=200, width = "auto",
                      draggable = TRUE,
                      wellPanel(
                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                            aa")
                    ), style = "opacity: 0.9"
```

Comment: I have a case where user can drag the absolutePanel around the screen. In that case even if i  do reposition, while dragging the absolutePanel, am getting the same type of issue. pls let me know the way to fix this issue in selectizeInput.