# How to correct - selectizeInput getting displayed above the absolutePanel

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

Given below the code I used for displaying `selectizeInput` and `absolutePanel`. `selectizeInput` is not getting merged with the page background. it is displaying above the `absolutePanel`.  pls help

ui.r

```
library(shinydashboard)
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      dashboardPage(skin = c("blue"),
                    dashboardHeader(title = "R Tools"
                    ),
                    ## Sidebar content
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                        menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
                      )

                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                                      box(
                                        title = "Tools", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                                        collapsible = TRUE,width = 4,
                                        uiOutput("showtxttruevalue"),
                                        uiOutput("showddllalternate")
                                      ),
                                      absolutePanel(
                                        bottom = 20, right = 60,top=200, width = "auto",
                                        draggable = TRUE,
                                        wellPanel(
                                        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                        aa")
                                        ), style = "opacity: 0.9"



                    )

      )


    ))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$showtxttruevalue <- renderUI({
 numericInput(inputId="txttruevalue", label="TrueValue", value = 0)
})


output$showddllalternate <- renderUI({
 selectizeInput("ddllalternate", "Alternate:",c('unequal','less','greater'),   selected='<>')
 })



})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [selectizeInput getting displayed above the absolutePanel - how to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700593/selectizeinput-getting-displayed-above-the-absolutepanel-how-to-avoid)

Comment: i have added my comment there in detail about my objective of the question. but no response. hence posted as new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `z-index` CSS attribute of the selectize is 1, so it is displayed above your absolutePanel.

Try adding this as the first element of your `fluidPage` to change the z-index to 0:

```
tags$style(type="text/css", ".selectize-input{ z-index: 0; }")
```

[image]